# Problem to deploy web app spring on elastic beanstalk. Return 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

https://github.com/488442/vm

This is my GitHub of the project , when i deploy it on amazon web services (elasticbeanstalk) and i try to open it , return only 404 obviously on Tomcat server work perfectly.
I have tried everything , exporting the project in war file.

this is the code of application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }
```

EDIT:
the resource work at 100% in localhost with Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5 and it's the same version on AWS.

This is the log from AWS , any ideas?

```
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.283 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.32.0
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.283 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.284 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.14.97-74.72.amzn1.x86_64
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.284 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.284 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-0.42.amzn1.x86_64/jre
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.284 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_191-b12
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.284 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.284 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/share/tomcat8
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.284 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat8
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.284 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.725 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.777 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.808 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.810 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.824 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1967 ms
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.925 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.930 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
26-Feb-2019 17:31:13.972 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT]
26-Feb-2019 17:31:19.605 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
26-Feb-2019 17:31:27.516 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/baeldung/spring/PersistenceJPAConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 46 more

26-Feb-2019 17:31:27.525 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

26-Feb-2019 17:31:27.526 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [13,553] ms
26-Feb-2019 17:31:27.535 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Feb-2019 17:31:27.564 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Feb-2019 17:31:27.580 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in  13755 ms
```

some news?

Answer (score 1):

What does your source bundle look like? [The docs state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html) that a requirement for the archive is that it must "[n]ot include a parent folder or top-level directory" but your GitHub repo has a top-level directory. You might also want to [enable CloudWatch logs or retrieve the instance log](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-logs.html)s to get a better idea of where the web server is looking for files.

Here is an [example bundle structure](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-elastic-beanstalk-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/java-tomcat-platform-directorystructure.md) that might help.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for the specific problem?

Comment: Examine the structure of your source bundle (.zip or .war) and make sure that the code is in the top of the repo, or share the contents here. Or share the command you are using to create the bundle

Comment: i have loaded the log

Comment: Logs are helpful but I still think the structure of your .zip is incorrect. Can you open the zip and share what the directory and file structure looks like?

Comment: This is the structure of the zip file: spring-security-registration-master-->src-->main-->java,resources,webapp-->...

Comment: You need to get rid of the top-level directories. When you unpack the archive, it should put the code files right where you unpack it, not in a subfolder. You don't want it to create master, src, etc. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html

Comment: Added this link to my answer as well https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-elastic-beanstalk-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/java-tomcat-platform-directorystructure.md

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the problem, I tried to follow your guides step by step. I uploaded other types of projects always with the same zip / war file extracted directly from eclipse and they worked correctly. Thank you for the guides but have not solved the problem

Comment: Return the same stacktrace of the question

Answer (score 1):

In your code I see that you set your server.port to 8081 in application.properties. Try to remove this line to have it running on the default port.

**EDIT**:

Regarding the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html) it seems to me that Beanstalk listens on port 5000 by default. So at this point you can do one of the followings:

1. Set your application's server.port property to 5000, or
2. Override your Beanstalk instance's default by setting the PORT environment variable to match with your application's port (in your case, it's 8081).

Comment: I tried to use the default port 5000 replacing it to the current 8081 but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I have changed was rds setting security